# Does delphi-orm support enumeration types?

Tags: delphi, orm

Does [delphi-orm](https://github.com/danieleteti/delphi-orm) support enumeration types or assuming that it does, how to use enumeration types?

In the "Helloworld" example, I added a simple TGender type:

```
type
  TGender = (gtMale, gtFemale);

  [Entity('CUSTOMERS')]
  TCustomer = class
  private
    FName: String;
    FEMail: String;
    FID: Integer;
    FCreatedAt: TDate;
    FADDRESS: String;
    FGender: TGender;
    procedure SetADDRESS(const Value: String);
    procedure SetCreatedAt(const Value: TDate);
    procedure SetEMail(const Value: String);
    procedure SetGender(const Value: TGender);
    procedure SetID(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetName(const Value: String);
  public
    property ID: Integer read FID write SetID;
    property Name: String read FName write SetName;
    property Address: String read FADDRESS write SetADDRESS;
    property EMail: String read FEMail write SetEMail;
    [Column('CREATED_AT')]
    property CreatedAt: TDate read FCreatedAt write SetCreatedAt;
    property Gender: TGender read FGender write SetGender;
  end;
```

For a simple insert:

```
procedure SimpleInsert;
var
  dormSession: TSession;
  Customer: TCustomer;
begin
  dormSession := TSession.CreateConfigured(
    TStringReader.Create(Form1.Memo1.Lines.Text), TdormEnvironment.deDevelopment);
  try
    Customer := TCustomer.Create;
    Customer.Name := 'Daniele Teti Inc.';
    Customer.Address := 'Via Roma, 16';
    Customer.EMail := 'daniele@danieleteti.it';
    Customer.CreatedAt := Now;
    Customer.Gender := gtMale;
    dormSession.Insert(Customer);
    Customer.Free;
  finally
    dormSession.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The result is that GENDER is null:

[image]

(Gender is defined as INTEGER)

When loading the record, dorm reports an error:

"Unknown field type for gender"

Comment: There is surprisingly little mention of enums in that repository:
https://github.com/danieleteti/delphi-orm/search?q=Enum&unscoped_q=Enum

Comment: TGender **IS NOT** defined as Integer type! TGender is defined as enumerated type. Granted Delphi does assign each enumerated type member an Ordinal value which is then used internally when assigning or retrieving these values. But this does not make it an integer type

Comment: @SilverWarior: I mean in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the source it appears not. (At least for the SQLite adapter).

Anyway, the source for this part is pretty easy to understand and modify.

Here are the changes I made to add support for enumerations:

in `dorm.utils`:

```
function TdormUtils.GetFieldType
...
  else if (_PropInfo.Kind = tkEnumeration) and (_PropInfo.Name = 'Boolean') then
    Result := 'boolean'
  else if _PropInfo.Kind = tkEnumeration then
    Result := 'integer'
...
```

in `dorm.adapter.Sqlite3`:

```
procedure TSqlite3PersistStrategy.LoadObjectFromSqliteTable(...);
var
  PropTypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
...
begin
...
      else if CompareText(field.FieldType, 'integer') = 0 then
      begin
        if (Field.RTTICache.RTTIProp <> nil) and
           (Field.RTTICache.RTTIProp.PropertyType.TypeKind = tkEnumeration) then
        begin
          PropTypeInfo := Field.RTTICache.RTTIProp.PropertyType.Handle;
          v := TValue.FromOrdinal(PropTypeInfo,
            AReader.FieldAsInteger(AReader.FieldIndex[field.FieldName]));
        end
        else
          v := AReader.FieldAsInteger(AReader.FieldIndex[field.FieldName]);
        S := field.FieldName + ' as integer';
      end
...
end

procedure TSqlite3PersistStrategy.SetSqlite3ParameterValue(...);

begin
...
  else if CompareText(aFieldType, 'integer') = 0 then
  begin
    if aValue.Kind = tkEnumeration then
    begin
      ADB.AddParamInt(aParameterName, aValue.AsOrdinal);
      GetLogger.Debug(aParameterName + ' = ' + IntToStr(aValue.AsOrdinal));
    end
    else
    begin
      ADB.AddParamInt(aParameterName, aValue.AsInteger);
      GetLogger.Debug(aParameterName + ' = ' + IntToStr(aValue.AsInteger));
    end;
  end
...
end
```

In the database, the field should be declared as INTEGER.